# Calculating the Balance for Near Address 35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

I tried calculating the balance for address 35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near.

As shown in the explorers the balance for the above address is 3.50036 Ⓝ. But when I see the transactions the deposit is 0 for all the transactions.
Url from explorer:
https://nearblocks.io/address/35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near#
https://explorer.near.org/accounts/35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near

Even when I try the below curl queries for the transaction hash and the address I don't get the amount transferred to this address.

Please let me know how is the balance for this address calculated and how can I get them.

And also how can I get the lockeup balance as shown in the below screen shot.

```
Transaction Hash: GMnNyCRhFZvWThSs6sCurzh3AL4HJ4kAnEQprSm2QPQ2
curl --location 'https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": "dontcare",
  "method": "tx",
  "params": ["GMnNyCRhFZvWThSs6sCurzh3AL4HJ4kAnEQprSm2QPQ2",
    "35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near"]
}'

Transaction Hash: C651EP3V6yojcKf5uQyvhLqi2Q8iKFtFHxE8aJz8f14q
curl --location 'https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": "dontcare",
  "method": "tx",
  "params": ["C651EP3V6yojcKf5uQyvhLqi2Q8iKFtFHxE8aJz8f14q",
    "35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near"]
}'

Transaction Hash: 93u2H6FGbYM6mYk5RXSbGyyLRAvdYjyz4amwsTnhiWKW
curl --location 'https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": "dontcare",
  "method": "tx",
  "params": ["93u2H6FGbYM6mYk5RXSbGyyLRAvdYjyz4amwsTnhiWKW",
    "35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near"]
}'
```

URL: https://wallet.near.org/profile/rw3f1.near
[image: https://wallet.near.org/profile/rw3f1.near]

Answer (score 1):

The balance for the lockups could be unintuitive.
I guess your question is about these 3.5 NEAR, why you don't have access to this amount.
They are blocked by the lockup contract: https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/master/lockup/src/lib.rs#L31-L33

So, until the contract is active, you have no access to this amount. But, this amount still belongs to the account.
Be careful, different wallets may show this information in different ways.

Comment: There should be a transaction in which this balance would have been transferred or locked so can we get those transactions.

Answer (score 0):

The balance of `35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near` is currently [delegated](https://explorer.near.org/transactions/93u2H6FGbYM6mYk5RXSbGyyLRAvdYjyz4amwsTnhiWKW#A46ydubqkjPer6AXy11r7iLAckNFYCp54zhqAJp23FsE) to `figment.poolv1.near` [staking pool contract](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/staking-pool).

[image]

> But when I see the transactions the deposit is 0 for all the transactions.

The transactions were initiated by the lockup contract owner account, and did not attach any tokens to it, but the lockup contract then makes a cross-contract call to the staking pool contract with NEAR tokens attached (unfortunately, Explorer does not show that in the UI).

Comment: Can we get the  balance for the address that is 3.50036 Ⓝ from any of the Near RPC APIs

Comment: We also have a node setup so can we get this lockup balance from it.

Comment: And also is there a way that we can get the Reserved for storaget, Locked, Unlocked and Available to transfer balance for the address

Comment: @Swornatoya Sure, use the Account RPC API: https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/contracts#view-account, it will get you 3.50036 Ⓝ

Comment: As to the values reported by Wallet, I recommend digging into [the source code](https://github.com/near/near-wallet/blob/002f98115b948746de7945b88c18d8c36b6780ad/packages/frontend/src/components/profile/balances/BalanceContainer.js#L140-L228)

Comment: Using https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/contracts#view-account we can get the balance of the address but is there a way that we can get it from any transactions also regarding the values reported by wallet can we not get from the node

Comment: Transaction status does not include the state changes, but you can use [`EXPERIMENTAL_changes`](https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/contracts#view-account-changes) (in fact, it is quite an old API, so it is not that experimental anymore) and request state changes for a specific account in a specific block (where a relevant receipt is processed).

Comment: Re: "regarding the values reported by wallet can we not get from the node". I referred you to the actual code where you should start digging to learn how those values are computed from the data returned from the node

Answer (score 0):

@Vlad Frolov :
Could not get much help from the actual code. Can we get anything from the below code but it throws error while I run it. Anything specific to pass through the method name

```
const axios = require('axios');
async function getLockupBalance(accountId) {

  try {

    const rpcEndpoint = 'https://rpc.mainnet.near.org'; // Replace with the appropriate endpoint
    const response = await axios.post(rpcEndpoint, {
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      id: '1',
      method: 'query',
      params: {
        request_type: 'call_function',
        finality: 'final',
        account_id: '35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near',
        method_name: 'get_account', // Replace with the actual view function name
        args_base64: ''
      }
    });

    const lockupBalance = response.data.result;
    console.log('Lockup balance:', lockupBalance);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
  }
}

// Usage example

const accountId = '35b2e85e2e7add13abcd8ae62998cbfad9bad5bf.lockup.near'; // Replace with the NEAR account ID you want to query
getLockupBalance(accountId);
```